# Is there a way to totally ignore all of the MyPy errors in specific project packages?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Is there a way to ignore all of the errors in certain packages within my project?

Some of the code in my project is compiled Protocol Buffers code which doesn't pass a MyPy check. It all lives within a directory /myproj/generated/proto.

Here's what I have in my mypy config file:

```
[mypy-myproject.generated]
ignore_missing_imports = True
ignore_errors = True
```

What can I add to this to make it ignore all error messages generated from an analysis of anything that's inside of myproject.generated?

This is a duplicate of a [question on GitHub](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6155).

Comment: There is already [an answer](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6155#issuecomment-451933525) for the question on Github. Did it work for you?

Comment: Not quite, but I discovered you can include path globs in addition to dotted module expressions in the ini file... that actually worked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a glob.

```
[mypy-myproject.generated.*]
ignore_errors = True
```

But you have to assure that you have `__init__.py` in `/generated`

Answer (score 1):

You can **also** use ignore an entire folder or file via the [`exclude`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html?highlight=exclude#confval-exclude) option.

Here is an example of an ini file:

```
[mypy]
exclude = generated
```

Well, of course it's a crutch. I do not pretend that this is the most correct way.