# Mypy- Report Generation for only specified files

Tags: python, mypy

I'm looking at the doc [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#report-generation):

Is there a way to ignore certain files when making a report? I'm seeing some files I don't want a report of, and I'm wondering if I can make a runtime configuration or somthing to ignore them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

You can ignore a whole package (cf this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54075244/11384184) and the relevant [Github issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6155)).

Ignoring just a file was discussed in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/964) which recommended other ways to achieve the same result (`@no_type_check` decorator for functions, checking the Python version, custom mypy call script, ...) and was closed as a duplicate of this [other issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/626) which happens to have been closed 13 days ago (2021-06-10) by Guido because "it didn't seem all that important", although the [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#id41) states :

> A # type: ignore comment on a line by itself at the top of a file, before any docstrings, imports, or other executable code, silences all errors in the file.

In another related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4675#issuecomment-813495933), someone mentions there is a command option for exactly that since version `0.810` (2021-02-10) : [--exclude](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-exclude) (cf [commit](https://github.com/python/mypy/commit/6bfc2dbc0e877408f5b70b86818683cd211c0031#diff-07fe2aa6ca4b414246227427e4eb27845bfffde835998796996142d743c8196d))

> A regular expression that matches file names, directory names and paths which mypy should ignore while recursively discovering files to check. Use forward slashes on all platforms.

Here is my setup :

```py
# file: ok.py
a: int = 4
```

```py
# file: bad.py
a: int = "definitively not an integer"
```

- with MyPy v`0.800` :

  ```
  $ mypy . --txt-report report0800; cat report0800/index.txt
  bad.py:2: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "int")
  Generated TXT report (via XSLT): /home/stack_overflow/PyCharmProjects/68071098/report0800/index.txt
  Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 2 source files)
  Mypy Type Check Coverage Summary
  ================================

  Script: index

  +-----+-------------------+-------+
  | Module | Imprecision       | Lines |
  +-----+-------------------+-------+
  | bad |   0.00% imprecise | 2 LOC |
  | ok  |   0.00% imprecise | 2 LOC |
  +-----+-------------------+-------+
  | Total |   0.00% imprecise | 4 LOC |
  +-----+-------------------+-------+
  ```
- with MyPy v`0.812` :

  ```
  $ mypy . --txt-report report0812 --exclude 'bad.py'; cat report0812/index.txt
  Generated TXT report (via XSLT): /home/stack_overflow/PyCharmProjects/68071098/report0812/index.txt
  Success: no issues found in 1 source file
  Mypy Type Check Coverage Summary
  ================================

  Script: index

  +----+-------------------+-------+
  | Module | Imprecision       | Lines |
  +----+-------------------+-------+
  | ok |   0.00% imprecise | 2 LOC |
  +----+-------------------+-------+
  | Total |   0.00% imprecise | 2 LOC |
  +----+-------------------+-------+
  ```

I tried on a real project and the regex behaviour seemed finicky (or maybe I did not understood well the docs), but it worked nonetheless.

Comment: just what I needed! Thank you!